# Create a List from a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, csv

I am new to pyhon and i can't find a way to manipulate a string of mine into a List.

I read a file that contain this exact output (it is one parameter of a csv file):

```
[{a,b,c},{aa,bb,cc}]
```

I want to format that string to get an array of 2 objects :

```
[{
    val_a: 'a',
    val_b: 'b',
    val_c: 'c'
},
{
    val_a: 'aa',
    val_b: 'bb',
    val_c: 'cc'
}]
```

Is there a simple way of doing this ?

Comment: You should know that we don't call `array` in Python but we call it `list`.

Comment: Noted. I updated the post to fix the spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first off, what you're calling an "object" in your description is really a JavaScript-like definition of an object, one that is not commonly used in other languages. This older style of JavaScript object, without an actual class declaration that constructs objects with pre-defined sets of attributes and methods, is a little too explicitly just a string-keyed hash table that you can bolt fully object-oriented features onto after the fact. It's close to Python's `dict` syntax (where `dict` is a fully generalized hash table, but with no ability to bolt on additional class behaviors after the fact), but it's still frowned upon if you intend to make actual *objects* with a consistent set of attributes; using plain `dict`s doesn't clearly indicate which keys are expected to exist (maybe the next `dict` has an extra key, and the one after is missing a key), and Python makes no real effort to optimize for large numbers of plain `dict`s that just happen to all be defined with the same set of keys (most Python objects *are* implemented with an underlying `dict` to store their attributes, and they have optimized `dict` to reduce memory usage in that use case, but it relies on the existence of a class for the `dict` to store the shared keys on for retrieval by future instance `dict`s).

The simplest way to do this Pythonically would be to use a `namedtuple` (a lightweight class defining lightweight immutable objects with a fixed set of keys; it's actually lower memory usage than the equivalent manually defined class unless that manually defined class explicitly uses `__slots__` to opt-out of a per-instance attribute `dict`):

```python
import json
import re
from collections import namedtuple

MyClass = namedtuple('MyClass', 'val_a val_b val_c')  # Defined once at top-level of the file for
                                                      # reuse; makes a lightweight tuple subclass
mystr = '[{a,b,c},{aa,bb,cc}]'

# Make string legal JSON (needs tweaking based on real data)
mystr = mystr.replace('{', '[').replace('}', ']')  # Sets are unordered, we don't want to lose ordering by converting to set
quoted_str = re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1"', mystr)

# Decode from JSON to Python types
orig_data = json.loads(quoted_str)

# Convert from list of three-lists to list of MyClass instances
obj_data = [MyClass(*datagrp) for datagrp in orig_data]

print(obj_data)

# If you'd like it to look like a dict, you can expand from memory-efficient namedtuples to less efficient dicts as needed
print([obj._asdict() for obj in obj_data])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZLNbtswDIDvegqiOdhenQDDLgOGndpLB3Qb0GMaBIxEJ2pkyZPkZEaQZ88o2Wl6ng80RUrkx59uiDtnv3zt/OWi2875CG/BWTHpnkTjXQvSGUMyamcDTC6LLanYd4aEeB4eDIYA3z9Yy2KyFjUUBzRrhCQ3WcqiApjBIzXakgJnJQFGiK6bGzqQAddA3BE02rBwXsB/fTMuoA/0DVrcUwAEo7e7eKQkIVNC6DcyUeYMoh1C9FxGsTxhvanluT4hK6zJ86oQYgbPHAn4krZbMLRFAz9efv2E0hKpABwb98m1wZDrYgC@ojBi9R48/xeeOoOS23RKDVoW1c1yTpbV2KIXigzuCXrrvCJPqoYjgXK2iHBEm5oGxgWC7M65B56XPZCP6cTuQFH86V0ktR4JPC247tIX5evxvuJsvrh7/XzHSmarUqGPJJ3i5qfx5xI50O@8LRCHjoJwXm/XqTIOmHZmYRyqUN4S5TAPI8kYx@gQx9F6onk6hYw/ma9rpG2IyCvBOTZv1xTLyVt@Soat76q0GDAd@A28A62E6LgTsbw@zyRPDQyuLxSn4xHqqXFuP54RlJaxTldAogX626FVI3ZLrfPDnJpGS0324@6P/MTQN28KxDMLkHaC1MSyZJjFGkPyliM7WzL3RLmqLpd/)

which, on Python 3.8 and higher, produces the output:

```python
[MyClass(val_a='a', val_b='b', val_c='c'), MyClass(val_a='aa', val_b='bb', val_c='cc')]
[{'val_a': 'a', 'val_b': 'b', 'val_c': 'c'}, {'val_a': 'aa', 'val_b': 'bb', 'val_c': 'cc'}]
```

Pre-3.8, you'd get the result of the final output as `OrderedDict`s, not `dict` (until 3.7, `dict` wasn't guaranteed to preserve key order, so they used `OrderedDict` initially to do so), but if you don't need reliable ordering of keys in the output, changing the final line to:

```python
print([dict(obj._asdict()) for obj in obj_data])
```

will do so.

If you don't want `namedtuple`s for whatever reason (mostly commonly because you don't want the objects to behave as `tuple`s, having length and iterability, or you want them to be mutable), you can define a similar lightweight class with [the `dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), it's just a *little* more verbose:

```python
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass  # On 3.10+, use @dataclass(slots=True) if you want reduced memory per instance and no auto-vivification if you assign to non-existent attribute
class MyClass:
    val_a: str
    val_b: str
    val_c: str
```

and that defines all the common stuff you need use the rest of the code from before, with the only change being to change `obj._asdict()` to `asdict(obj)` (`dataclasses` made it a top-level function of the `dataclass` module instead of a method on the type to avoid polluting the class's namespace). You never need the `dict()` wrapping `namedtuple` requires pre-3.8, because:

1. `dataclasses` was only introduced in 3.7 (which has insertion-ordered plain `dict`), and
2. Because of that, it defaulted to `dict` from the beginning

Comment: To be clear, I chose one of *many* options for parsing your original string. Since your string was very close to two widely supported formats (JSON and Python literal syntax), I just picked one with a good Python parser, massaged from *almost*-JSON to actual JSON, then let the JSON module do the complicated work. If your real data is different from what you showed (maybe not all data consists of the "word characters" `\w` recognizes), you'll have to tweak.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes so much more sense. I Really struggle with the concept and definitions that comes with the previous languages i worked with (mainly Java and Javascript). Thx for taking the time to clarify that !